# JQuery mobile hiding a dynamically generated button

Tags: jquery-mobile, show-hide

I have written some code that generates a set of buttons when the page loads using a loop, each iteration of the loop increments an ID value to assign to the new button.

I originally wrote it using standard JQuery but because of the way JQuery Mobile works, I am having to rewrite it.

```
<a id = "<?php echo $button_id_add_to_cookbook ?>"onclick="update_button('<?php echo $button_id_add_to_cookbook ?>')" data-role="button">Send</a>
```

the function update button is below, at least the test trial version.

```
function update_button(id)
{
$(id).click(function(){
    $(id).toggle();
});
}
```

I'm having a hard time finding 2 accounts that say how to do this the same way so don't think this is correct.

The goal it to dynamically generate a set of buttons and when a button is clicked, it will call some code to alter a mysql database and on success hide the button that called the function. For this example I just want to hide the button when t was clicked.

Can anyone help me with the correct way to do this, the page should not refresh, just update the button element.

Answer (score 0):

I think it was a spacing issue causing problems, for dynamic id content this seemed to work as a replacement function.

```
function update_button(id)
{
$('#' + id).closest('.ui-btn').hide();
}
```

if this will lead to any issues in the long term please let me know!